# Creaating a javascript object with computed name

Tags: javascript, object

how would I make an object in javascript with a computed name.

Context:
I am making an add-on that will sit in the browser, log each hostname visited, create an object named after each one. I'm replacing "." with "_"
So for example on this site it would create a stackoverflow_com object.

is this possible?

another example would be
var 1+1 (with the variable actually being 2)

I know brackets make this possible with properies but I don't know how to do it with the name itself.

Comment: why do you need this? on which context will you call these variables name?

Comment: window['yourObjName'] = yourObject, I think...

Answer (score 2):

You need to store them either in a global object (like `window`) or preferably an object of your choosing

```
var mySites = {};
mySites["stackoverflow_com"] = "foo"; // access as mySites.stackoverflow_com or mySites["stackoverflow_com"]
mySites[1+1] = "bar"; // access as mySites[2];
```

More info:  [JavaScript property access: dot notation vs. brackets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets)

Comment: Interesting downvote. Care to comment?